# What is HTML Entity '&#13;'?

Tags: html, xml

I'm generating an XML Document object via the DOMDocument class. In the process, some kind of whitespace within elements is being converted into `&#13;`. It's pretty difficult to search for this one since search engines treat this character as whitespace.

How do I scrub this character out of my xml output, or at least replace it with a different, preferable whitespace character?

Thanks.

Comment: If you needed to search in a search engine just escape it. \&\#13; works in google.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

ASCII code 13 corresponds to a carriage return (in PHP, it's `"\r"`).

Answer (score 9):

You scrub this character out of your output by not putting it there in the first place. Look for the code that puts the carriage return in your XML, and delete it.

Comment: My guess is that because in many instances, you do not have access to the generated text. Say you are pulling it from a file, or an email. But in my opinion, it would be the right answer if you are generating the xml file from your own data.