# Removing '&#13;' from CSV file in unix

Tags: unix

I have a csv file called file.csv, which is created by dumping in a specific content of a xml file. The content of the csv file is like :

```
000000,gh9876547658732176,Ratboard,Legret,5428765432890898655,,&#13;
000001,98JHYTR,JHi,U,Kunal,0987 Ramnagar Fort,PO Box 0987,c/o Mary,NewJersey,Ket,Lat,54322,,X,X,V,,,,8,,&#13;
555555
```

First I was perplexed as to what `&#13;` is and then i read [ENTITY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082253/what-is-html-entity-13), which made me realize it's a carriage return. In my case , it appears at the end of the first 2 lines of the file.

I was trying to delete that grouping of characters using the command below :

`tr -d '&#13' < file.csv > file1.csv`

But the problem is that it does not just delete that group , but **also any other occurrences of** `&`, `#`, `1` , `3`, `13` **from every line  of the file, which is undesirable.**

**Can any one tell me how to remove just this grouping of characters** (`&#13;`)  **from the file and not any individual characters ?** Any help will be greatly appreciated .

Comment: this question belongs on superuser.com

Comment: @user0000001 : I don't think so, it does belong here as well. I did not find anything in the FAQS telling me that, i cannot post a unix related question here . And i have been posting a lot of unix related question here for a long time and nobody told me otherwise .

Comment: Yes, but this is a shell related question not programming.

Comment: @user0000001 : Well,it's not.The confusion may be because i mistagged it . You can say it's  a command related question. Because, the command that's dumping the file is causing the entity to appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `sed`:

```
sed 's/&#13//g'
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. In case i want to do the same to a xml file, will it work ?

Comment: @TheDarkKnight If it contains that exact string, yes. If it contains a real CR, you need to strip `\r` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will try this one out and let you know .

Answer (score 1):

sed will work `sed -e s/",&#13;"//g`

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response .

Answer (score 0):

this will help you..

`sed -e 's/&#13;//g filename.csv'`