# Character strange html

Tags: php, html

Ok, maybe is simple question but i am generating a xml from custom posts of wordpress, the problem is a textarea field of acf, i put a break line here and the code generate give me this character `&#13;` but i not find nothing about that in google and str_replace not make nothing about that. i already remove the `<br />` and `<br>` but that character I can't.

this is my actual code about that

```
str_replace('&#13;', '', str_replace('<br />', '', strip_tags($addressValue['c_restaurant_map_address'], '<br /><br/><br>')));
```

Comment: See [What is HTML Entity '&#13;'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082253/what-is-html-entity-13)

Comment: As an aside, `str_replace` will accept _an array of characters_, so you can do all your replaces in one: `str_replace(['<br>', '<br />', '&#13;'], '', $target);`.....

Comment: You may be interested in `html_entity_decode()` : http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: Thanks i think with that i can resolve the problem :D